# C# how to make it so office doesn't start when using Word's spell check

Tags: c#

I'm using Microsoft Word in my app to use a spell check dialog. Whenever you use the spell check, Office opens. Is there any way to stop that?

Here's my code:

```
Word.Application app = new Word.Application();

int errors = 0;
if (richTextBox1.Text.Length > 0) {
    app.Visible = false;
    this.BringToFront();

    // Setting these variables is comparable to passing null to the function.
    // This is necessary because the C# null cannot be passed by reference.
    object template = Missing.Value;
    object newTemplate = Missing.Value;
    object documentType = Missing.Value;
    object visible = true;

    Word._Document doc1 = app.Documents.Add(ref template, ref newTemplate, ref documentType, ref visible);
    doc1.Words.First.InsertBefore(richTextBox1.Text);
    Word.ProofreadingErrors spellErrorsColl = doc1.SpellingErrors;
    errors = spellErrorsColl.Count;

    object optional = Missing.Value;

    doc1.CheckSpelling(
        ref optional, ref optional, ref optional, ref optional, ref optional, ref optional,
        ref optional, ref optional, ref optional, ref optional, ref optional, ref optional);
    object first = 0;
    object last = doc1.Characters.Count - 1;
    richTextBox1.Text = doc1.Range(ref first, ref last).Text;
}

object saveChanges = false;
object originalFormat = Missing.Value;
object routeDocument = Missing.Value;

app.Quit(ref saveChanges, ref originalFormat, ref routeDocument);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Word Spell Check pops up hidden and "freezes" my App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382454/word-spell-check-pops-up-hidden-and-freezes-my-app)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa171830(v=office.11).aspx